# CSS Design System

Tags: html, css, design-patterns

I'm thinking of making a CSS design system which includes classes like

```
.text-red {color: red}
```

Im super confused, I love the design system approach but anomalies are a big concern.

UPDATE: This is how what I have so far to generate colours
[Background Utilities Via SCSS @each](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7LLd.jpg)

On hover of an element I want to make it darker or lighter dynamically. I was thinking of creating a class like .darken or .lighten and I have it decrease a certain amount of colour, would I just inherit the colour and use something like -50% or something along those lines.

I guess I could create like 10 utilities with inherit as the background color and then decrease a certain amount like 50% or 25%

But how that work for on hover.

UPDATE:
This is what I have so far, not efficent but its kind of what I want with hardcoded colour

```
//Base Background Colour 
@each $name, $colour in $colours {
    .background-#{$name} {
        background-color: $colour; 
    }
}
//Darken Background Colour
@each $name, $colour in $colours {
    .background-#{$name}-light {
        background-color: lighten($colour,10%); 
    }
}

@each $name, $colour in $colours {
    .background-#{$name}-dark {
        background-color: darken($colour,10%); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what would be an anomaly versus a normalcy?

Comment: So you have a background colour e.g. green, but on a specific selector like on a single button you want it to be a darker element than the defined colour in the class. The effect on this specific button should not affect the rest of the application, contained as such.

Answer (score 0):

You could for instance add an extra class name:

```css
.text-red {
  color: red;
  font-family: ebrima;
}

.text-red.darker {
  color: rgb(110, 20, 20);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>

<h1 class="text-red darker">Hello there, I'm text!</h1>

<h1 class="text-red">I'm also text!</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

Wouldn't that be good enough?

Or would that be way too labor intensive?

Comment: Hmm interesting approach. I was thinking of the lines of you have say a button with a .button and .red and on hover of this button you want this single element to be darker on initial load or on hover. Im trying to make something similar to airbnb did https://airbnb.design/building-a-visual-language/, all I want to know is what is the best way to handle anomalies e.g. making one element darker than usual, Im just a little confused.

Comment: I assume you are going for at least partial modularity with your css design system? Also, sadly, I don't quite see why the link is related, maybe upload an image instead of a link? Let me try again then; You want to be able to add a class / id to an element such that it will get a darker shade of whatever color is applied to the element on hover?

Comment: Yeah something like that, I have updated my question with what I have so far so you can understand what I'm attempting to do

Comment: Ok I will take a look

Comment: Sadly, I only use pure CSS, I haven't really mustered enough courage to begin learning SASS ;). I also know using JavaScript would be kind of impractical for you. There is probably a better way, but I only see one solution: 

`.text-red {} .text-red.darker{} .text-blue {} .text-blue.darker {} .text-green {} text-green.darker {}` and so on. It is, though, possible to do this in Javascript. That would even allow for rgb values if youre creative enough with your codes.